# SQL How to access element of a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table [pets]

| Animal | prev_store | curr_store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | ABC | DEF |
| Dog | ABC | GHI |
| Fish | DEF | XYZ |
| Snake | XYZ | JKM |

I also have this other table [pet_store]

| Store | Country |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | England |
| DEF | Denmark |
| GHI | England |
| XYZ | Denmark |
| JKM | Denmark |

I want to check for each animal in pets table, whether the prev_store and curr_store is in the same Country, and if so, make a record of the Country.

| Country | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| England | 1 |
| Denmark | 2 |

```sql
SELECT pet_store.Country, count(pet_store.Country)
FROM pet_store, pets
WHERE pets.prev_store = pet_store.Store
and pets.curr_store = pet_store.Store
GROUP BY pet_store.Country
```

Unsure about how I would then select the animals's Country in relevance to the prev and curr store.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `pets_store` twice, in two roles, in the query:

```
WITH
-- your data, don't use in query ..
pets(Animal,prev_store,curr_store) AS (
          SELECT 'Cat'  ,'ABC','DEF'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dog'  ,'ABC','GHI'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Fish' ,'DEF','XYZ'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Snake','XYZ','JKM'
)
,
pets_store(Store,Country) AS (
          SELECT 'ABC','England'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DEF','Denmark'
UNION ALL SELECT 'GHI','England'
UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ','Denmark'
UNION ALL SELECT 'JKM','Denmark'
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT
  prev_stores.country AS country
, COUNT(*)            AS occurrences
FROM pets
JOIN pets_store prev_stores ON prev_store = prev_stores.store
JOIN pets_store curr_stores ON curr_store = curr_stores.store
WHERE prev_stores.country = curr_stores.country
GROUP BY prev_stores.country;
-- out  country | occurrences 
-- out ---------+-------------
-- out  Denmark |           2
-- out  England |           1
```